# Clicking button from one page to anchor link down to open a specific accordion tab in another page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to anchor link to specific accordion tab on another page of the site by pressing a call to action button on my current page. When pressing the button it should go to another page to open the specific tab.

```
 <div class="main-tab">


    <input type="radio" name="subject" id="radio-1" checked="checked">
    <input type="checkbox" name="subject" id="check-1">
    <label for="radio-1">subject 1</label>
    <label for="check-1">subject 1</label>
    
    <section>
    
    </section>

<input type="radio" name="subject" id="radio-2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="subject" id="check-1">
    <label for="radio-2">subject 2</label>
    <label for="check-2">subject 2</label>
    
    <section>

    
    </section>
</div>
```

The button

```
<a href="https://www.this/page#radio-2">subject 2</a>
```

Comment: Am I correct in saying you just want the link to be opened in a new tab?

Comment: You can use query params to solve this, you can pass some params from one page and write a script on another page to read those params and do certain action according to the value of the params.

Comment: Try using this: 

`<a href="https://www.this/page#radio-2" target="_blank">subject 2</a>`

Comment: I want the link to open a tab accordion. As the first one is checked and shows the first tab i want the link to hyperlink to the accordion tab  and open the second tab.